# file_get_contents with url as variable

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Can I use something like this to retrieve the page that is external with respect to the domain.

```
<?php
    $q_pass =$_REQUEST['query_passed'];
    $fetcher = "http://www.abc.com/search?q=".$q_pass;
 $homepage = file_get_contents($fetcher);
 echo $homepage;
?>
```

I have passed a variable and want to retrieve the result from the abc.com. Can $fetcher can be passed over to file_get_contents to retrieve the contents of the page? I am getting blank page when I hit this php page. But its again working fine if I use something like

```
 <?php
        $fetcher = "http://www.abc.com/search?q=query";
        $homepage = file_get_contents($fetcher);
        echo $homepage;
 ?>
```

What is happening here? Is there some technical explanation for this?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Try debgugging `$_REQUEST["query_passed"]` to find out what goes wrong

Comment: For some reason, `$_REQUEST['query_passed']` is not set. Is this a GET or a POST request? What's the query string in the browser window (the bit after the `?`)?

Comment: $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use urlencode on $q_pass. I'm guessing your passing a value with spaces in it in query_passed.

Comment: Its the spaces I have messed up with.. Used un-encoded String while passing it as parameter to the PHP file.